# Метод List<T>.Contains(T) для классов наследников C#

Tags: c#, ооп, list, интерфейс

Имеется `abstract class FileOrFolder` и `class Folder : FileOrFolder`. Как правильно унаследовать `IEquatable<T>`, чтобы для `List<FileOrFolder> list` можно было использовать `list.Contains(item)`, где `item` - экземпляр класса `Folder`?

Comment: Пробовали перегрузить Equals() и GetHashCode()?

Comment: @tym32167 IEquatable требует только определения Equals. Перегрузка GetHashCode не дала результата.

Comment: @tym32167 помогло

Comment: Чтобы это работало со списком, вам достаточно просто перегрузить функции, реализовывать IEquatable нет необходимости

Answer (score 0):

```
class class Folder : FileOrFolder , IEquatable<FileOrFolder>
{
    public bool Equals(FileOrFolder folder)
    {
        return FullName == folder.FullName;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        var folder = obj as FileOrFolder;
        return FullName == folder.FullName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return FullName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Сравнивал по полю FullName